# How to increase the speed of scoring/predicting one observation with multiple models?

Tags: r, performance, web-services, prediction

I'm developing a solution in R which is a series of logistic regressions predicting different outcomes.

All the models take in the same featureset - approx 200 features. The idea is to deploy the models as a web service and that this web service can be called with a single observation and return a list of scores, corresponding to the list of logistic regression models that i have trained and deployed.

To my own surprise this actually works. The entire setup works and delivers the results i would like... BUT the results take too long to return. For my actual setup it takes about 6 seconds to return 26 scores using 26 different models on a single observation. When evaluating which parts of my code took the longest to run I found that 5.5 seconds where spend in the for each loop that does the actual scoring.

**My question is: How can the speed of predicting be increased?**

The solution I've implemented is reproduced here with mtcars and linear model:

```
ylist <- c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp" )
flist <- c("vs", "wt")
tlist <- c(ylist, flist)

subset.mtcars <- mtcars[,tlist]

listofmodels=list() 

for (y in ylist) {
  form <- as.formula(paste(y,"~", paste(flist, collapse="+")))
  mod <- glm(formula = form, data = subset.mtcars)
  varname <- paste("Model_", y ,sep ="")
  
  listofmodels[[varname]] <- assign(varname, mod)
  
}


mypredict <- function( vs, wt) {
  
  newdata <- data.frame(vs = vs, wt = wt)
  dfout <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 0, ncol = 2))
  colnames(dfout) <- c("model","score")
  
  for (modelname in names(listofmodels))
  {
    score <- predict(listofmodels[[modelname]], newdata, type = "response")
    dfout[modelname, ] <- c(modelname, score)
  }
  
  dfout[order(dfout$score),] 
  
}


mypredict(1, 2.32)
```

Using mtcars it seems to run quite fast in the code I've provided above, but for some reason I'm experiencing a bottleneck issue with my setup. Since each of the predict calls I'm making takes about 0.2 seconds and the prediction loop causes predictions to be serially executed it causes my webservice to perform slowly. What am I missing? Is there a smarter way to vectorize? To my understading lapply is just a wrapper for a loop. Am I mistaking?

Comment: Have you tried pre-allocating `dfout`? Perhaps you could profile your code to see the bottlenecks.

Comment: If you are having bottlenecks with your setup, then you should create example that represents "your setup". Now you have provided very simplified setup that works just fine. Maybe you do not need foreach? because for small iteration count it does not pay of.

Comment: Although I know it is a difficult task solve a problem when you don't have access to my setup, I am hoping that one of the heroes in here can offer som perspectives.  How would I be able to avoid the for each loop?   I'm essentially trying to pass the same input (newdata) to 26 different functions. Can I do that without for each loop?